# Is privacy policy url is necessary for uploading app to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, privacy-policy

I am going to upload my first app to the app store before i submit i have some to ask so that i can avoid my app from rejection. First my app is not using any data from user , no permission required so is privacy policy URL is necessary to upload my app . secondly is it necessary to add app icon on prepare for submission page .
 finally any helpful guideline so that i can avoid app rejection.

Comment: Privacy policy URL is mandatory. If you don't have a website you can use a facebook page link. If you have added app icon in assets you don't need to upload app icon on prepare for submission page

Comment: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev219b53a88

Comment: i have website but on website i don't have a privacy policy page  so what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

> You should ask these kind of questions in other communities of **StackExchange**. **StackOverflow** is just for programming questions.

Yes it should provided. Also you must have **terms and conditions** and **privacy policy** inside your app somewhere reachable or it will be rejected.

App icon in appstore connect is necessary for prepare for submission and actual app icon is a need for not getting rejected.

Comment: Sometimes you are not at place you should work but someone asks you something about that. It’s up to you to answer or not. I believe teaching community rules beside programming at same time is a good idea to follow.